# Does my contribution to an editorial project merit a more formal acknowledgment?

Tags: etiquette, editors, collaboration, interpersonal-issues, networking

For the past several years, I've worked remotely and without pay in an archive in order to assist a colleague (who has actually left academia) with a book project. The project consists of compiling an edited edition of an intellectual figure's papers. Because I have access to the papers, am interested in/familiar with the topic, share mutual friends and mentors with this person, and have extensive experience in archival research, I answered a request for assistance they sent to another member of my department.

Over the course of these years, I've spent many hours in the archives assembling, scrutinizing, photographing, and editing materials for this colleague, as well as reviewing and proofreading the final manuscript. I've discovered a number of unknown documents that have now made their way into the final volume. Although the work has occasionally cut into my own research time, I continued it because I enjoyed it, as well as my developing relationship with this person. My colleague and I have exchanged extensive correspondence about the project, during which my contribution was repeatedly characterized as essential to the completion of the volume. What began as a friendly offer turned, over several years, into a more substantial undertaking and partnership.

Relatively recently, I asked my colleague if they would consider adding me as a co-editor to the volume in acknowledgment of my contribution. (As I'm a much more junior person--and, unlike my colleague, still in academia for now--this would also materially help me in obvious ways.) They declined without offering an explanation, although they reiterated their gratitude.

I'm wondering how you would proceed in this situation. Does my contribution sound like it might merit a more formal attribution in the volume--whether as co-editor, associate/assistant editor, or one who receives the designation "with the assistance of"? Am I wrong to even ask? Should I simply cut my losses and take it as a learning experience?

A few things to note:

- The book already has two additional editors besides this person: a scholar who has since passed away, and an independent scholar who is no longer involved with the project. The extent to which these two people--from whom my colleague inherited the project--have contributed to its final form are unknown to me.
- There is a line thanking me in the book's introduction, but it characterizes my contribution as merely secretarial, which isn't consonant with my understanding of it or with conversations/correspondence I've had with my colleague about it (with respect to having found unknown materials, made substantial revisions to the manuscript, etc.).

Comment: I suggest you name or tag a field, as most people on this site are in math or the sciences, and likely don't have much experience with this kind of work.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion, based on the limited information in your question.

I think "editor" should be reserved for people who have contributed substantially to the intellectual content of the work - things like deciding what to include, annotations, context. It does not sound as if your contribution is of that kind.

But it seems to me more than merely secretarial. You might try to argue for a more substantial acknowledgement - one that mentions the particular kinds of contributions you made.

Answer (score 2):

Seems rather late in the process to be asking these sorts of questions.  I think your most reasonable request at this point would be for a more accurate description of your contribution in the intro.